# Convert an integer(seconds) into the format of an hour: minute: seconds in c

Tags: c

```
input:140153(seconds)
output:38:55:53
```

I have solved this problem in this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int N;
    double hour;
    double minute;
    double seconds;
    scanf("%d",&N);

    hour=N / 3600.0;

    double floating = hour;
    double fractional, integer;

    //split the floating value(hour) into the integer and decimal
    fractional = modf(floating, &integer);
    minute=60 * fractional;

    double floatingUpdate = minute;
    double fractionalUpdate, integerUpdate;
    //split the floating value(minute) into the integer and decimal
    fractionalUpdate = modf(floatingUpdate,&integerUpdate);
    seconds = 60 * fractionalUpdate;
    printf ("%g:%g:%g\n", integer, integerUpdate, seconds);

    return 0;
}
```

Would you propose any simplification for my solution? Would I face any problem with some specific conditions? Is the way I solved this kind of problem efficient or not?

Comment: Is that your real indentation - or did it get mangled when you copied it into the question?  I recommend you [edit] to fix that up.

Comment: Note that C has some standard functions for dealing with time, such as [`gmtime()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/gmtime), although it's not a perfect fit if you want the hours component to be larger than 23.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When we write

> ```
> scanf("%d",&N);
> ```

it's important not to ignore the return value from `scanf()` (that indicates how many values were successfully converted).  Otherwise, we're working with the uninitialised value `N`.

---

Use of the `modf()` function requires a declaration:

```
#include <math.h>
```

But we would be better working with integers instead (use the `/` and `%` operators).

---

Presentation of negative values is strange:

> -70:-29:-29

Normally, we'd just print that as `-70:29:29`.

I'd be inclined to just work with unsigned values, and get that working well, before extending to negatives.

---

Variable naming is inconsistent (singular `hour` and `minute`, but plural `seconds`).  `N` is a poor choice for a variable name - choose something more meaningful and lower-case; convention reserves upper-case for macros.

---

We should make the declaration of `main()` be a prototype.  Also, it's permitted to omit the return statement in `main()`; since we always return success, let's remove that clutter.

---

## Modified code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long total_secs;
    while (scanf("%lu", &total_secs) != 1) {
        // consume some input
        if (scanf("%*s") == EOF) {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        printf("Enter a valid integer: ");
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    unsigned long hour = total_secs / 3600;
    unsigned int minute = total_secs / 60 % 60;
    unsigned int second = total_secs % 60;

    printf("%lu:%u:%u\n", hour, minute, second);
}
```

Comment: @chux Thanks for edit - should have compiled, even for a small change!

Comment: I am going to follow the strategy you proposed. Thank you for your facilitation. Keep up the good work.

Comment: if (scanf("%*s") == EOF) {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        } please explain this part of code in words.

Comment: @ashiful, That part reads (at least some of) the erroneous input from the standard input stream and discards it, so that we can re-try the `scanf("%lu")`.  If there's nothing left to read, we don't re-try (which we know would immediately fail), but instead terminate with an error status.

Answer (score 4):

> Would you propose any simplification for my solution?

As code is effectively changing H:M:S --> time and then later time --> H:M:S, this becomes a  fine opportunity to consider helper functions.

This promotes [divide and conqueror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm) and makes the sub-steps smaller and easier to maintain.

```
// Each returns an error flag.
bool HMS_to_seconds(int *seconds, int h, int m, int s);
bool HMS_from_seconds(int *h, int *m, int *s, int seconds);
bool HMS_to_string(size_t sz, char *hms, int h, int m, int s);
bool HMS_from_string(int *h, int *m, int *s, const char *hms);
```

These then become flexible building blocks.

I'll go deeper into one of them.

```
// Convert hour, minute, second into a standard string form.
bool HMS_to_string(size_t sz, char *hms, int h, int m, int s) {
  if (hms == NULL || sz == 0) {
    return true;  // Bad argument
  }

  // Bring into primary range  (h:int, m:0-59, s:0-59)
  if (m < 0 || m >= 60 || s < 0 ||| s >= 60) {  // Could use macros like SECPERMIN 60 ...
    int seconds;
    if (HMS_to_seconds(&seconds, h, m, s) || HMS_from_seconds(&h, &m, &s, seconds)) {
      hms[0] = 0;
      return true;  // Range error
    }
  }

  int cnt = snprintf(hms, sz, "%d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s);
  if (cnt < 0 || (unsigned) cnt >= sz) {
    hms[0] = 0;
    return true;  // Buffer too small;
  }

  return false;  // No error
}
```

Make the helper functions as robust as desired.

Comment: Thank you for your presence. I am going to try the suggestion you provided.